# Regex to add a space after each comma in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that is made up of a list of numbers, seperated by commas. How would I add a space after each comma using Regex?

Comment: You dont' necessarily need to use regex if you only want a space after each comma. Replace each comma with a comma and a space.

Comment: @Chase: Replacing *all* occurences is usually best done with a regexp though (with the `g` flag).

Comment: @pimvdb My mistake. I was under the impression Javascript's replace method replaces all occurrences by default, not just the first match.

Answer (score 36):

### Simplest Solution

```
"1,2,3,4".replace(/,/g, ', ')
//-> '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

### Another Solution

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',').join(', ')
//-> '1, 2, 3, 4'
```

Comment: What if there are multiple spaces after comma? like "1, 2,3,4" or "1,     2,3,4". It works when there is no space after comma but if single or multiple comma already exists, it will add additional space to existing space. I think, we don't want that.

Comment: Just update the RegExp to you needs: `.replace(/ *, */g, ', ')`

Answer (score 27):

I find important to note that if the comma is already followed by a space you don't want to add the space:

```
"1,2, 3,4,5".replace(/,(?=[^\s])/g, ", ");
> "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

This regex checks the following character and only replaces if its no a space character.

Answer (score 12):

Another simple generic solution for comma followed by n spaces:

```
"1,2, 3,   4,5".replace(/,[s]*/g, ", ");
> "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Always replace comma and n spaces by comma and one space.

Comment: This is wrong. It removes 's' from your string. Try This: "s1,s2,s3,s4,s5".replace(/,[s]*/g, ", ")

Answer (score 7):

Use [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

```
> var input = '1,2,3,4,5',
     output = input.replace(/(\d+,)/g, '$1 ');
> output
  "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Comment: why such a complicated pattern for this task? Why not just replace ',' with ', '? Perhaps a better pattern would do a lookahead and only replace commas that don't already have a space after them.

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat. Yes, `input.replace(/,/g, ', ')` would also work. Does it really matter?

Comment: Does it matter? I think it does. When teaching someone how to program we should teach them to strive for the simplest solution.

Comment: When I have 2 regular expressions to check, I look for the differences. In this case: What if there isn't a digit in front of one of the commas? What if there is a comma at the start of the string, or two commas next to each other? If those cases will never happen, or you don't care what happens in those cases, then there's no need to use the more complicated version

Answer (score 6):

Those are all good ways **but** in cases where the input is made by the user and you get a list like "1,2, 3,4, 5,6,7"

..In which case lets make it idiot proof! So accounting for the already formatted parts of the string, the solution:

```
"1,2, 3,4, 5,6,7".replace(/, /g, ",").replace(/,/g, ", ");

//result: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7" //Bingo!
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var numsStr = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var regExpWay = numStr.replace(/,/g,", ");
var splitWay = numStr.split(",").join(", ");
```

Comment: The split and join method is the faster of the two in this case. You can run a test on the speed difference here: http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join/6

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a regex for this, use split and join.

It's simpler and faster :)

```
'1,2,3,4,5,6'.split(',').join(', '); // '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6'
```

Answer (score 2):

As I came here and did not find a good generic solution, here is how I did it:

```
"1,2, 3,4,5".replace(/,([^\s])/g, ", $1");
```

This replaces comma followed by anything but a space, line feed, tab... by a comma followed by a space.

So the regular expression is:

```
,([^\s])
```

and replaced by

```
, $1
```