# Add space after comma to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
var $string = 'hello,world';

$(".content").text(function(i, $string) {
    return $string.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});
```

Aiming to add comma after space. What am I doing wrong? The problem is likely how I am using the variable in the function. Entry level stuff.

Comment: Are you trying to change the `$string` variable or the text of the `.content` element? Your code seems to indicate both, but only the latter will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to add a space after each comma in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621066/regex-to-add-a-space-after-each-comma-in-javascript)

Comment: `$(".content").text($string.replace(/,/g, ", "));` is working fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I am trying to change the `$string` variable by adding space after comma and then insert it into `.content`. You mentioned in an answer that you had a solution to this without creating a function?

Comment: See my comment on @RenzoCC's answer. Also note that `$string` shouldn't have the `$` prefix as it holds a string, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Yes, basically the problem is that you are mistaken about the use of $string argument in the inner function here. First, it will *hide* the other $script value is 'hello, world' . And as [per the docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function), this $string argument will be populated with the current value of the text of the element you are trying to modify.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I haven't come across info on why I shouldn't use the `$` prefix for string variables. Is this a standard practice when coding JS?

Comment: It's standard practice for jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't include arguments in your anonymous function since this is overwriting your $string value... As suggested by @RoryMcCrossan you don't need a function

```js
var $string = 'hello,world';

$(".content").text($string.replace(/,/g, ", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: In this case you don't need the `function` at all.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How would you write it without a function then? Please post answer.

Comment: `$('.content').text($string.replace(/,/g, ', ');`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For your understanding, your code is currently working like this one :

```
var $anotherstring = 'hello,world';

$(".content").text(function(i, $string) {
    return $string.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});
```

(because the inner variable parameter of function is not the same as the first one, and *hide* the first `$string` you defined with the same name)

The way you are using `text` with the inner `function(i, $string)` will work *if the current text value of the element* is 'hello,world'

(see the [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function))

```
$(".content").text('hello,world'); // just to set the value of the .content element for the example, you can ignore this if this already the case

$(".content").text(function(i, $string) {
    return $string.replace(/,/g, ", ");
});
```

So the above code will work if you want to **transform the existing content**.

If you simply want to use the value of another variable, and not the old content of the .content element, you can simply do :

```
var $string = 'hello,world';

$(".content").text($string.replace(/,/g, ", "))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this way

```js
let $str = 'hello,world';
$(".content").text($str.replace(/,[s]*/g, ", "));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```